# Nodes with same name in different packages

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS and I have a question regarding ROS nodes. Is it possible to create two nodes with same name in different packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256096/nodes-with-same-name-in-different-packages/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2017-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can create multiple nodes with the same name in different packages, but there are two things to watch out for if you really want to do this:

- ROS requires each node to have a unique name at runtime, so you'll need to give each node a different `name=""` in your launch files, use anonymous names, or use the `__name:=` parameter to change the node name when starting it from the command line
- Since a catkin workspace is a single cmake project, each target name needs to be unique across the entire workspace. To get around this, you'll need to use a unique name for each target, and then set the executable name afterwards with set_target_properties:

Package A cmakelists.txt:

```
add_executable(packageA-node node.cpp)
set_target_properties(packageA-node OUTPUT_NAME node)
```

Package B cmakelists.txt

```
add_executable(packageB-node node.cpp)
set_target_properties(packageB-node OUTPUT_NAME node)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-03-04**:
Thanks for answering

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2018-03-10**:
It should be set_target_properties(packageB-node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node) instead of set_target_properties(getpose_grade OUTPUT_NAME getpose)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to add to this, since I stumpled upon it today:

AFAIK it is also possible to have multiple nodes with the same name in different packages if you are not building with `catkin_make`, but instead with `catkin_make_isolated` or `catkin_tools`, since with these tools every package has it's own build space. That way you will also not have to apply the workaround @ahendrix suggested.

---

Originally posted by [CJuette](https://answers.ros.org/users/32093/cjuette/) with karma: 21 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-02-19**:
Keep in mind that that the workarounds I've suggested apply at both build and runtime. Even if you use `catkin_make_isolated` or `catkin_tools` to build binaries with the same name, you'll still have to deal with duplicate node names at runtime.